# Maxima - plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in plotting range

Tags: plot, maxima

I mean to plot a function of one variable, which uses a paramter that is not included as an argument to the function.
Now I want to `plot2d` the function, so I mean to assign a temporary value to the parameter for plotting. I.e.:

1. Assign parameter value
2. Plot2d
3. Forget parameter value

What I did is

```
f(u):=a*u;
a=1;plot2d(f(u),[u,0.2,1]);
```

but I get the error

```
plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in plotting range.
plot2d: nothing to plot.
```

How would I proceed?

PS: I actually mean to work with functions using many parameters, so if excluding them as arguments is workable, I'd rather do it for convenience. Up to now, I have been `integrate`ing, `diff`erentiating, `factor`ing, etc., with no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-answering: It was probably a silly question (I am a newbie), but just in case it helps others...

```
f(u):=a*u;

a:1;
plot2d(f(u),[u,0.2,1]);
kill(a);
```

To avoid assigning and clearing:

```
params : [a=1];
fnew : subst(params,f(u));
plot2d(fnew,[u,0.2,1]);
```

Other options are posted in the comment by Robert Dodier.

Comment: You can also temporarily bind variables to values using `ev` like this: `ev(whatever(a, u), a = 1);` or, at the input prompt, just `whatever(a, u), a = 1;`. So you example would be: `plot2d(f(u), [u, 0.2, 1]), a = 1;`